# Can't ping two internal networks

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, ping

I have created two machines on virtual box. Each machine has one internal network interface.

To set the static ip on each machine I used the command `ifconfig eth1 ip mask up`.

These are the IPs:

Machine1:

- eth1: 10.20.0.1
- eth2: 10.70.0.1

Machine2:

- eth1: 172.40.0.2

Then in machine2:

```
route add -net 10.20.0.0/24 gw 172.40.0.2
```

But I am not able to ping from machine1 to machine2 and also not able to ping from machine2 to machine1. Do you see why?

Comment: There might be other issues, possibly affected by configuration details like whether the virtual NICs are treated as bridged or if they are expected to get routed by IP.  We will likely assume you're using /24 (so 10.20.0.1 and 10.70.0.1 are on different subnets, which they wouldn't be if you're using /8) unless specified otherwise, but you should specify.  (/24 refers to the size of the subnet mask, so another way to communicate this to the networking experts is by reporting every subnet mask).  Does the host machine have virtual NICs to communicate to the VMs?  What IPs are used on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A route is required at the other end to return the packet on. On machine 1 try adding your route to machine2:

```
ip route add 172.40.0.0/24 dev eth1
```

Now you should start to see return on the packets

Answer (score 0):

A router has to be connected to the targeted subnet, meaning it has to have an IP adress in its range or at least a configured interface route.
In your case you have to set up a second IP on one of the 2 machines or use an actual router with both subnets configured.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the rout add -net command should not solve that issue?

Comment: Its not possible just have 1 interface in machine 2 and ping working?